# Twitter request token returns 401 unauthorized. I cant find what I did wrong

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter, oauth

I need to do twitter sign in for mobile apps. Thus far I have tried a lot of libraries including tweetsharp and linq2twitter. But I am getting nowhere. With all this trouble, I resorted to webclient calls, but I am once again stuck. When I make the call, I get the 401 Unauthorized error. I include my code here. Can you guys see anything wrong at all ? I am really stuck with this.

```
        string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        string oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        string oauth_version = "1.0";
        string oauth_consumer_key = "iD1232134AQ2Pb6Q";
        string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

        SortedDictionary<string, string> sd = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        sd.Add("oauth_version", oauth_version);
        sd.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
        sd.Add("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
        sd.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
        sd.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
        UrlEntity callback = new UrlEntity();
        callback.Url = @"//tweeter";
        string encodedCallbackUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(callback.Url);
        sd.Add("oauth_callback",encodedCallbackUrl);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: randomAgent HTTP Client");
        wc.Headers.Add("Host: api.twitter.com");
        wc.Headers.Add(@"Accept: */*");
        UrlEntity url = new UrlEntity();
        url.Url = @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
        string signature = CreateSignature(url, sd);
        sd.Add("oauth_signature",signature);
        string dataValues = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in sd)
        {
            dataValues += pair.Key + "=''" + pair.Value + "'',";
        }
        dataValues = dataValues.Substring(0, dataValues.Length - 1); // cuts off the last,
        string headerVal = " Oauth " + dataValues;
        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization",headerVal);
        wc.UploadString(@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "");
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += WcOnDownloadStringCompleted;
```

Below is the code to make the signature.

```
public static string CreateSignature(UrlEntity url, SortedDictionary<string, string> sd)
    {
        string parameterString = "";
        SortedDictionary<string, string> sd2 = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> parameter in sd)
        {
            string encodedKey = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Key);
            string encodedvalue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value);
            sd2.Add(encodedKey,encodedvalue);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in sd2)
        {
            parameterString += pair.Key + "=" + pair.Value + "&";
        }

        parameterString = parameterString.Substring(0, parameterString.Length - 1); // cuts off the last &


        string signatureString = "POST&";
        var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url.Url); // percent encode URL 
        signatureString += encodedUrl + "&";
        signatureString += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameterString); // percent encode entire parameter string

        string consumerSecret = "supercorectConsumersecretfromtwitterwebsite";
        string signingKey = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumerSecret) + "&";
        HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));

        string signatureStringFinal = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signatureString)));


        return signatureStringFinal;
    }
```

It is a bit messy, but I am stuck. The following links might help.
    https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter
    https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token
    https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

EDIT:

I have taken a look at the request using fiddler.
The response message has this in it...

"Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

Which likely means the oauth signature is wrong. But I have looked and I have not seen anything.

Comment: I would recommend to look at Asp.Net Identity. http://www.asp.net/identity or the tag on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity

Answer (score 0):

I am not a .net expert but am setting up something similar for PHP and note that the Oauth attributes must be in alphabetical order. From a quick look the examples here don't appear to be. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature.